# Как используется 'in' в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Capitals = dict()

Capitals['Russia'] = 'Moscow'
Capitals['Ukraine'] = 'Kiev'
Capitals['USA'] = 'Washington'

Countries = ['Russia', 'France', 'USA', 'Russia']

for country in Countries:
    if country in Capitals:
        print('Столица страны ' + country + ': ' + Capitals[country])
    else:
        print('В базе нет страны c названием ' + country)
```

Как используется 'in' в строке 'if country in Capitals:' 
и как её использовать?
Как её можно ещё использовать, кроме цикла for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `var in object` является синонимом вызова метода [`object.__contains__(var)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) и осуществляет проверку вхождения `var` в `object`. Метод `__contains__()` должен быть реализован в `object`.

> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if
>   item is in self, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should
>   consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the
>   key-item pairs.
>
> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test
>   first tries iteration via `__iter__()`,

---

Примеры:

```
In [351]: lst = [1,2,3]

In [352]: 2 in lst
Out[352]: True

In [353]: lst.__contains__(2)
Out[353]: True

In [354]: 'b' in 'abcd'
Out[354]: True

In [355]: 'abcd'.__contains__('b')
Out[355]: True
```